# How to set the correct screen size

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I'm trying to create a maze game in emu8086. First i want to make the display screen white in full screen then print the coordinates of the maze background in black, but when i make it full screen it gets pixelated..
How do i set the whole display screen in full screen to white and print the character 219 in black instead of silver.

These are some screenshot of my problem:

http://prntscr.com/n9m5xm  --Small Screen
http://prntscr.com/n9m7v5  --Full Screen

```
mov ax,19 
int 10h

mov ah, 09h
mov cx, 1000h
mov al, 20h
mov bl, 0F0h  ; This is Black & White.
int 10h

mov  dl, 0   ;Column
mov  dh, 1   ;Row
mov  bh, 0    ;Display page
mov  ah, 02h  ;SetCursorPosition
int  10h


mov cx,0
first: 
mov  al, 219
mov  ah, 0Eh  ;Teletype 
int 10h  
inc cx  
cmp cx,80
jne first
```

Comment: That's an emu8086 issue. You are setting mode 13h which is 320x200, changing the size of the emulator window won't change the resolution set by your program. Of course the emulator must scale the 320x200 framebuffer, this is an easy task but apparently emu8086 can't handle it.

Comment: So what can i do to make my game play in fullscreen > :(

Answer (score 1):

Your game is playing in "fullscreen". But the screen of your code is virtual. And this "fullscreen" is set by *emu8086*. So you cannot really set fullscreen mode in an emulator. Your (emulated) code will always execute in a window that is considered to be a "full" screen.

To make the emulator window extend to full screen, use the <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination or something like this (see the manual of your emulator).